# Node.js GitHub oAuth callback using dynamic host?

Tags: node.js, github, oauth, passport.js

I've been making a Node app that uses GitHub for authentication via `Passport.js`.

Recently I put my app on heroku, and now I seem to only be able to either authenticate on heroku or localhost, not both...

GitHub has a defined callback parameter:

[image]

How do I make this be generic so it will work if I'm using either my public instance or testing locally?

My auth code is taken right from the passport-github example:

```
passport.use(new ghStrat({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create multiple keys, and then switch based on the environment. Some people use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine if they are running in production or not, and choose a config file based on that.

You can set NODE_ENV to "production" on heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#setting-node_env

and in your code switch on NODE_ENV

```
var config

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config = require("./config.production.json")    
} else {
    config = require("./config.dev.json")
}
```

where your two config files look like

```
{
    "clientId": "...",
    "clientSecret": "...",
    "callbackURL": "local or production uri"

}
```